# C# UpdateProgress which displays a variable from the running code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an updateprogress in my aspx file, which has a "label control" in it with a text "Loading...", while I run my code, there is a "for loop" in my code. While this loop continues, I want to show the current row number in my update progress, so that user can see how much rows left until it ends.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's good to use `BackgroundWorker` here?